# Why the name of metadata of Azure Blob must obey the naming rules of C# identifiers?

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Question is clear I think. To illustrate the question better, let me explain with some example:
In Azure Blob Storage Service, when I want to set a metadata to a blob, I'm using following code and metadata name:

```
# working    
blob_service.set_blob_metadata(container_name="mycontainer",
                                   blob_name="myblob",
                                   x_ms_meta_name_values={'metadata1': 'aaaa'})
```

It is working perfectly, but when I want to create a metadata which name is like **"1metadata"**
it does not allowed:

```
# not working
blob_service.set_blob_metadata(container_name="mycontainer",
                                   blob_name="myblob",
                                   x_ms_meta_name_values={'1metadata': 'aaaa'})
```

Then, I found such a restriction:

> The name of metadata in azure must obey the naming rule of the **C#**
>   **identifiers**(variable names)  So, I can not use "1metadata" name as a metadata name.

e.g:

```
metadata_name  # OK
meta-data      # NOT
metadata12345  # OK
1234metadata   # NOT
```

My question is 
**"Why azure has such a restriction?"**

Comment: According to documentation, hyphen are not allowed. Here is a useful link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx

Comment: I know, also we cannot start with digits. It has the same rule with C# identifier rules. But I am asking why? There should be a reason to have such a restriction in documentation???